# smbclient: Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: debian, domain-controller, samba4

until yesterday I had a functioning Active Directory Primary Domain Controller running on a raspberry pi.  Now it seems I cannot get the 'samba' service to listen at all.  This is since performing an upgrade.

> ```
> root@r2d2:/etc#  /etc/init.d/samba start
> [ ok ] Starting nmbd (via systemctl): nmbd.service.
> [ ok ] Starting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.
> [ ok ] Starting samba-ad-dc (via systemctl): samba-ad-dc.service.
> root@r2d2:/etc#
> ```

That looks fine, I suppose but `smbclient -L localhost -U%` gives the error message quoted in the title.

I have been googling this for a while and am unsure what the issue is.  I have imported a (replacement) startup script, but apart from that I have made no changes.

The underlying issue is, I think, in the startup/init.d procedures, but I do not know what to do next.

> ```
> root@r2d2:/etc# netstat -lntp
> Active Internet connections (only servers)
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5910          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      804/Xvnc
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      734/xrdp-sesman
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      547/sshd
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      543/cupsd
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      612/xrdp
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      644/apache2
> tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      547/sshd
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      543/cupsd 
> root@r2d2:/etc#
> ```

I am using internal DNS.

---

I notice the following, and this gets to the crux of my confusion - googling the issue did not make it easy to establish how one should start samba

`log.smbd`

> ```
> [2016/05/17 09:56:52.566097,  2] ../source3/lib/interface.c:341(add_interface)
>   added interface eth0 ip=169.254.144.46 bcast=169.254.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
> [2016/05/17 09:56:52.566286,  2] ../source3/lib/interface.c:341(add_interface)
>   added interface eth0 ip=10.10.10.32 bcast=10.10.10.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
> [2016/05/17 09:56:52.566510,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1297(main)
>   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone.
>   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting smbd if required
> ```

`log.nmbd`

> ```
> root@r2d2:/var/log/samba# cat log.nmbd
> [2016/05/17 09:56:19,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:908(main)
>   nmbd version 4.2.10-Debian started.
>   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2014
> [2016/05/17 09:56:19,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:743(lpcfg_map_parameter)
>   Unknown parameter encountered: "password level"
> [2016/05/17 09:56:19,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1626(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
>   Ignoring unknown parameter "password level"
> [2016/05/17 09:56:19,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:743(lpcfg_map_parameter)
>   Unknown parameter encountered: "update encrypted"
> [2016/05/17 09:56:19,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1626(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
>   Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
> root@r2d2:/var/log/samba#
> ```

I am currently using [this](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/InitScript) startup script (which I added after the problems began) and this seems to result in a new (note the timestamps do not overlap with the 2 previous snippets) `log.samba` file containing :

```
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.069201,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:324(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/winbindd: Failed to exec child - No such file or directory
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.070100,  0] ../source4/winbind/winbindd.c:49(winbindd_done)
  winbindd daemon exited normally
task_server_terminate: [winbindd child process exited]
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.074784,  2] ../source4/dsdb/repl/drepl_partitions.c:116(dreplsrv_load_partitions)
  dreplsrv_partition[CN=Configuration,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.075325,  2] ../source4/dsdb/repl/drepl_partitions.c:116(dreplsrv_load_partitions)
  dreplsrv_partition[CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.075730,  2] ../source4/dsdb/repl/drepl_partitions.c:116(dreplsrv_load_partitions)
  dreplsrv_partition[DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.076810,  2] ../source4/dsdb/repl/drepl_partitions.c:116(dreplsrv_load_partitions)
  dreplsrv_partition[DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.077271,  2] ../source4/dsdb/repl/drepl_partitions.c:116(dreplsrv_load_partitions)
  dreplsrv_partition[DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.084895,  2] ../source4/dsdb/kcc/kcc_service.c:127(kccsrv_load_partitions)
  kccsrv_partition[DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.085188,  2] ../source4/dsdb/kcc/kcc_service.c:127(kccsrv_load_partitions)
  kccsrv_partition[CN=Configuration,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.085368,  2] ../source4/dsdb/kcc/kcc_service.c:127(kccsrv_load_partitions)
  kccsrv_partition[CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.085508,  2] ../source4/dsdb/kcc/kcc_service.c:127(kccsrv_load_partitions)
  kccsrv_partition[DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.085635,  2] ../source4/dsdb/kcc/kcc_service.c:127(kccsrv_load_partitions)
  kccsrv_partition[DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=longmanrd,DC=infoforum,DC=co,DC=uk] loaded
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.088057,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
  STATUS=daemon 'samba' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2016/05/17 13:18:22.094641,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:211(samba_terminate)
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
  samba_terminate: winbindd child process exited
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant logs from /var/log

Comment: I am not sure which are the 'relevant' logs, but I am posting something of interest

Comment: I am not sure, but it should be /var/log/samba/log.smbd & /var/log/samba/log.nmbd on raspberry pi

Comment: that is the fragment I posted

Comment: @HughJones, which version of samba are you on? If it is 4.3.9 than there can be an issue with it. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1578576. You may try to install the latest fix and see if it helps. Just try an `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/sbin/winbindd: Failed to exec child - No such file or directory
```

Her's a simmilar issue http://www.spinics.net/lists/samba/msg133552.html

solution was to install winbind
http://www.spinics.net/lists/samba/msg133589.html

You need a separate winbind winh samba 4.2 +
http://www.spinics.net/lists/samba/msg133595.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess these issues are related to one of the updates that were released to fix the [Badlock Bug](http://badlock.org/).
The full list of fixes are listed in [Samba Security Releases](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/security.html) and the announcements for each patch-set provides useful information on what has changed.

After upgrading my old CentOS 5 system, I had issues connecting Winbind to an AD domain controller and the clue to fixing them was in [the announcement for CVE-2016-2115](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2016-2115.html) – *SMB client connections for IPC traffic are not integrity protected*.

This documented the new smb.conf option, `client ipc signing`. While the documentation recommends explicitly setting this option to `mandatory`, I found that `auto` also solved those issues so I added the following line to my `smb.conf` (under the `[global]` section):

```
client ipc signing = auto
```

I’m running Samba 3.6.23 so I can’t say if this would help you but there should be relevant information in the various announcements already mentioned. Best of luck with it (I wasted over 3 hours figuring this stuff out).